# How to get the rest of java Math funtions?

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone

I am using the Eclipse IDE and the CodeNameOne toolkit for all my programming at the moment and as some of my programs are now requiring some more complicated math I realized that I am missing some of the `Math` functions. The most important ones being `pow()`, `acos()`, and `asin()`. Any ideas on how to get them added in? All of my googling has been for not so far.

I have imported the class using `java.lang.Math` and while some methods are there I am missing some of them.

Comment: @JoãoDias You don't need to import anything, `Math` is in `java.lang`, so you can just `Math.pow(a, b)`.

Comment: @azurefrog the issue is that doing that is not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Not running? Not compiling? What code is causing what error under what conditions?

Comment: Have you created your own `Math` class?

Comment: I have not created my own Math class, and by not working I mean the IDE does not recognize those functions at all. It will recognize some of them like sin() and cos(), but not acos(), asin(), or pow(). I am using Math. in front of all of those of course.

Comment: You need to show us an [mre] and tell us exactly what error messages you are getting. There should be no problem using any of these functions, so we need to see what you are doing to get some idea of what the problem is.

Comment: This was closed by people who are unaware of Codename One which was tagged correctly. The correct answer is use MathUtil for extra APIs

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clear up front that you are using CodeNameOne.  After all, >>that<< is the crux of your question.  Best not to hide that vital fact by only mentioning it via a tag.

Comment: @Stephen C thanks, I did not know that codename1 was the most important piece of the puzzle at first, appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like codename1 overrides some of the java math functions.They can be accessed with codename1's MathUtil class. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score -2):

Those functions are available from the [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) class. You could statically import them all - `import static java.lang.Math.*;`.

Comment: I am aware of that, but for some reason, there are functions missing that should be included. So that doesn't really answer the question on how I can add those in.